# Копирование из одного класса в другой

Tags: jquery

В общем я написал функцию которая копирует из одного класса в другой класс, функция работает но он копирует только первый попавшийся класс остальные нет. Не могу разобраться в чем дело, целый день голову ломаю.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).bind("load", function() {
$(".cen-none").html($(".cen-yes").html());
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div style="border:1px solid #2c3c64; width:100px; height:150px;" class="contar">
 <div style="font-size:15px; color:red; display:none; margin:0 auto;" class="cen-yes"><p align="center">Значение1</p></div>
 </div>
 <div style="border:1px solid #2c3c64; width:100px; height:150px;" class="contar">
 <div style="font-size:15px; color:red; display:none; margin:0 auto;" class="cen-yes"><p align="center">Значение2</p></div>
 </div>
 <div style="border:1px solid #2c3c64; width:100px; height:150px;" class="contar">
 <div style="font-size:15px; color:red; display:none; margin:0 auto;" class="cen-yes"><p align="center">Значение3</p></div>
 </div>

<div class="cen-none"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Dostan, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 3):

Пробежаться циклом по всем элементам, собрать в этом цикле данные, которые потом добавить в нужный блок:

```
var htmlStr = '';
$(".cen-yes").each(function(){
    htmlStr += $(this).html();
});
$(".cen-none").html(htmlStr);

// или использовать второй способ

$(".cen-yes").html(function(){
    $(".cen-none").append($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: @Dostan, совершенно не обязательно нажимать "наградить", особенно, когда у вас баллов нет. Достаточно нажать "Палец вверх" напротив ответа, который вас устраивает.